# How create a select element from JSON data in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

I want to render a JSON into a select input with Vue.js, but I don't know how because the JSON is a bit complicated.

The JSON is:

```
{ 
   "08:00:00":"08:00:00 AM",
   "08:30:00":"08:30:00 AM",
   "09:00:00":"09:00:00 AM",
   "09:30:00":"09:30:00 AM",
   "10:00:00":"10:00:00 AM",
   "10:30:00":"10:30:00 AM",
   "11:00:00":"11:00:00 AM",
   "11:30:00":"11:30:00 AM"
}
```

As you can see, the JSON doesn't have a key to access into each element. This is the reason why I cannot render with the typical way. I'm implementing Vue.js in Laravel.

Comment: Assuming you have parsed that JSON into an object, you can call `Object.entries(obj)` to get a two dimensional array of keys and values.

Comment: Seems you do have keys, considering your first line `"08:00:00":"08:00:00 AM"`, the key being `"08:00:00"` and the value being `"08:00:00 AM"`

Comment: JSON is a string, do you mean a JavaScript object from parsed JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in your `data()` or `computed` part, the parsed JSON object. Then you do something like:

```
<template>
    <select>
      <option v-for="(value, key) in yourParsedJsonObject" :value="key">{{value}}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
           yourParsedJsonObject: JSON.parse(...yourjson...)
        }
    }
}
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional [index as second argument](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) -syntax of the `v-for` directive:

```html
<li v-for="(row, index) in json">
  {{ index }}: {{ row }}
</li>
```

Full source code: https://vuep.run/7d8683b3

Here an example with using select option elements:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="(row, index) in json">
    {{ index }}: {{ row }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Full source code: https://vuep.run/392a82b2

Comment: you might want to use `<option ... :value="{[index]:row}">` to keep `selected` an object instead of a string; edit: or any other suitable representation of `key/value`